# Moved Wordpress site to local server, now only header & footers display

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I moved a copy of a site developed on a NFSN server to a local machine running WAMP.  Everything works fine, except on all but the index page, only the header and footer appear. Help with this same issue (or very similar) has been been sought by other 2x before here, neither thread contains the cause or fix.  The problem is independent of the theme used.

Edit: Have determined that the missing content is due to the fact that a plugin won't work (Elegant Builder).  None of the typical responses to a misbehaving plugin have the desired effect, and there's another set of symptoms as well; the nav menus are scrambled and include some items not included on the remote site.

I copied the site to an alternate folder on the remote server, and just like when I copied the site to my local server, I used find/replace to update the links in the sql file before importing it to a new db--and got the exact same results as with the local site, so the problem is not with WAMP.  It's either a problem with the db or with what I'm doing with the export file with find/replace (using Sublime).

Comment: Have you check the apache error log?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; nothing relevant there, though.

Answer (score 0):

You might have not used the find and replace tool properly. Do another find and replace tool without http and www with just the domain name and its extension to see if there items in the database which are not updated yet.

Also, recheck the domain name you replaced by doing another find and replace.